# Get ID of a user in ASP.NET memebership

Tags: asp.net

i have just open a new website in ASP.NET Visual Studio 2010(Not using mvc).

i register into the asp.net membership.

lets say :

```
my username is :admin. 
email :admin@mpsiteil.com..
pass:123..
the page name : admincontrol.
```

--

and i want that a page will showed only to user "admin".

how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will lock down the entire site so that only admin can view it

```
<authorization>
  <allow users="admin" />
  <deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

this will lock down a specific path

```
<location path="/admins_only">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="admin"/>
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: this is nice, but lets sai i got 2 users i want, what do i do then ?:)

Comment: you can separate the usernames with commas, or you can change "users" to "roles" and separate multiples roles with commas as well.

Answer (score 0):

Authorization in ASP.NET WebForms is easily configurable via web.config:

[Setting authorization rules for a particular page or folder in web.config](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2008/09/29/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config.aspx)

Comment: thanks, if you can answer my answer blow it will be nice :D. thanks!